# using MySQL LOAD DATA with filename with accents

Tags: mysql

I tried to load a .txt file into a MySQL table (via LOCAL DATA), but the files that i'm using, some of them has a accent in their names that are not recognizable by MySQL. When I tried to execute the statement, I receive the following error:

> File 'C:\Users...\á.txt' not found (Errcode: 2)

I can avoid this error if I remove all the accents from my .txt files, then the database can locate those files.

Here the statement that I had executed:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\á.txt" INTO TABLE mytable COLUMNS TERMINATED BY ","LINES TERMINATED BY "\r\n"(column_a, column_b, column_c);
```

Comment: As a standard practice, I try to limit file names to have only standard alpha-numeric ASCII characters, hyphen, period and underscore (`a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9`, `.`, `-` and `_`). I recommend you rename those files and take measures to rename any other file that comes to you with "special" characters

Comment: I thought about it, but i'm trying to find another way to contour that.

Comment: Take a look at Connection Character Sets and Collations: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-connection.html

Comment: great tip, but it doesn't change the way MySQL behave. btw I'm gonna rename all the files.

Answer (score -1):

You must add a server configuration or command line option "character_set_filesystem" to the file system or your server.
Your file system will probably be in UTF-8 or ISO-8859-1 format.

[character_set_filesystem](https://mariadb.com/docs/server/ref/mdb/system-variables/character_set_filesystem/)

command line:

--character_set_filesystem=arg

e.g.:

--character_set_filesystem=utf8

Comment: MySQL still returns the same message. The data that go into the DB are ok. The problem is, only the character used on the file's name.

Comment: Try this (taken from [link](http://wiki.typo3.org/UTF-8_support#SET_NAMES_utf8.3B_and_SET_SESSION_character_set_server.3Dutf8.3B) if your filenames are in UTF-8:

 `SET NAMES utf8;`
 `SET SESSION character_set_server=utf8;`

You can add commands in a line separated by semicolon ";".

Comment: See [link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/de/server-options.html)
Add the option
`--character-set-filesystem=charset_name`